# Inserting QlineEdit.text() into Sqlite3 table give an error sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt4

I am using python 2.7 with pyqt4.10 and sqlite3 Db, trying to get the user input from `QlineEdit` to insert into `sqlite3` table that is already created

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `category_name` TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

And am trying to refresh the list in a `Qlistwidget` with the new data after adding the input 
Here is my full code :

```
    def proc():
    input_user = self.lineEdit.text()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
    conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?)", (input_user, ))
    conn.commit()
    conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
    conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories")
    category_all = c.fetchall()
    for items in category_all:
        self.listWidget.addItem(items)
    conn.close()
```

As you see i used `input_user = self.lineEdit.text()` to get the user input from the `QlineEdit`

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\townoftechwarehouse\add_category.py", line 63, in proc
    c.execute("INSERT INTO categories (category_name) VALUES (?)", (input_user, ))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: Please post your SOLVED section as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the problem was that am using Arabic characters which is not readable for qslite3 so I have to use `unicode`, here is the edit:

Changed :

```
input_user = self.lineEdit.text()
```

To :

```
   input_user1 = self.lineEdit.text()
   input_user = unicode(input_user1)
```